# jquery preview modified image in dialog

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with 2 file input which the user will select images to upload.

On submit when the images are uploaded, I first resize the image and merge it with another image using gd and this works fine.

What I want to do before the form is submitted, using Ajax on change of the file input, get the image, processes it on the server using gd (but not upload) and show the user the final result in a ui dialog for them to approve or not.

For reasons beyond my control I cannot use html5. I know you can't post files using Ajax and need to use jquery-iframe-transport or jquery-file-upload or some other plug-in like that.

What is recommended and how do I return the final image to display in the dialog, and if the user then click disapprove, how do I clear the file input field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

The above tutorial will show you how to do image upload using JQuery.

You can easily change the php file that handles the upload, show the image to the user, if they clicked disapprove, then simply remove the file from the server and start over.

Comment: Thanks..it looks like this is using jQuery ui form. Is this what is recommended?  Also, I am stuck on how to return the image to the dialog. I don't want to upload until the user submitted the form

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "jQ hi Form"... could you explain?

Comment: well I had a similar problem to yours and I used the above tutorial but I think you are better off using http://css-tricks.com/ajax-image-uploading/   it seems like it suits your needs better

Comment: Thanks....that looks very good i will try it...I wish that tutorial had some server code to show how it returns the image response.